# How to add FilterCriteria to a DynamoDB Stream CloudFormation template created by AWS Amplify?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Using the *AWS Amplify CLI* to create a Lambda trigger for a DynamoDB Table Stream. The [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/usage/lambda-triggers/#as-a-part-of-the-graphql-api-types-with-model-annotation) provided by Amazon is working as expected. However, I'm wanting to add filter criteria to the stream configuration. Amplify generates a CloudFormation template file. But, changes to this file will be overwritten with a future "push".

```json
{
  ...
  "LambdaEventSourceMappingName": {
    ...
    "Properties": {
      ...
+     "FilterCriteria": {
+       "Filters": [
+         ...
+       ]
+     }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Is there a way that I can add/overwrite attributes to a CloudFormation template generated by Amplify? Can this be done with Amplify's Custom Resources?

Answer (score 1):

Once you are edited cloudformation template in `amplify/backend/function/yourFunction/yourFunction-cloudformation-template.json` you need to `amplify env checkout dev` (change dev with your environment  name) before `amplify push`

Comment: Thanks! This appears to work. Any explanation for why running `checkout` doesn't overwrite like a `pull` would?